# HttpUrlConnection timeout when router has no input

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am using `HttpUrlConnection` to connect to a server. Problem is I am connected to the router via wifi. Hence I see network as on in my device. But router is not connected to any Internet input, and connection goes in infinite loop. Here is the code
private  String getHttpResponse(final String srcUrl) {

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(srcUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        mETag = readETagFromPrefForCategory();

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("If-None-Match", mETag);

        Log.v("abcd","####### before connection ######");

        urlConnection.connect();

        Log.v("abcd","####### after connection ######");
        mETag =  urlConnection.getHeaderField("ETag");

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) {
            Log.v("online","not modifed");
            return null;
        }

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Bad response [" + urlConnection.getResponseCode() + "] from (" + srcUrl + ")");
            return null;
        } 

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        fos = createJson();


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = "";

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            if(fos != null)fos.write(line.getBytes());
        }
        if(fos != null)writeETagForCategory(mETag);

        if (rd != null) {
            Log.v("online","buffered reader closed");
            rd.close();
        }

        return sb.toString();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", "Message - " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", "Message - " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", "Message - " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please send some code. It should not be infinite loop. It should be either `IOException` or block on read.

Comment: Which part goes into infinite loop? How? What `srcUrl` are you passing to you method?  
P.S. Your connection method should not be relevant here.